# Magento 2.2.4 - Add to Cart Not Working after Move Add to Cart Buttons Below Image on Product View

Tags: layout, magento2.2, addtocart

I have tried the following code to move add to cart buttons below image in catalog_product_view.xml

Button has moved below that element but Add to Cart Button is not Working anymore.

> ```
>   <move element="product.info.addtocart" destination="product.info.media" after="product.media"/>
> ```

Comment: Do you getting any console error? Is that shows cursor pointer  while hover on button?

Comment: No there is no console error, and it shows cursor point while on hover, add to cart button is clickable as well, but it is not adding product to cart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    <move element="product.info" destination="product.info.media" after="product.media"/>
```

Actually, in your code button out from add to cart form so form could not submit.

Comment: Welcome, happy to help you!

Comment: Hi kunj, on configurable products swatches are also coming before add to cart button after putting the above code, how can i move only add to cart button below images on configurable products. and swatches in product.info.main element. Help in this please.

Comment: Solved, by adding, the following code " <move element="product.info.options.wrapper" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info.price"/> "

Comment: Add to Cart is still not working in this case :( Still Confused. Please help @kunj

Comment: Actually, color swatch adding custom input field in that form so we can not move that swatch by XML.

Comment: How can we move that, I want to  shift only add to cart button. All other things will remain in product.info.main. How can i do that ?